# Abysmally slow performance of caret package, with multicore

Tags: r, performance, multicore, r-caret

I am going through the book "[Applied Predictive Modeling](http://appliedpredictivemodeling.com/)" by the author of the [caret](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/index.html) package.

The first example of a training on a svm takes hours to run on my 64 bit i7 16 GB xubuntu desktop [I gave up after 4 hours]. Since this is a "toy" dataset [800 rows, 42 variables], there sure must be a way to run this in a reasonable amount of time.

```
library(caret)
data(GermanCredit)

library(doMC)
registerDoMC(8)

GermanCredit <- GermanCredit[, -nearZeroVar(GermanCredit)]
GermanCredit$CheckingAccountStatus.lt.0 <- NULL
GermanCredit$SavingsAccountBonds.lt.100 <- NULL
GermanCredit$EmploymentDuration.lt.1 <- NULL
GermanCredit$EmploymentDuration.Unemployed <- NULL
GermanCredit$Personal.Male.Married.Widowed <- NULL
GermanCredit$Property.Unknown <- NULL
GermanCredit$Housing.ForFree <- NULL

## Split the data into training (80%) and test sets (20%)
set.seed(100)
inTrain <- createDataPartition(GermanCredit$Class, p = .8)[[1]]
GermanCreditTrain <- GermanCredit[ inTrain, ]
GermanCreditTest  <- GermanCredit[-inTrain, ]

set.seed(1056)
svmFit = train(Class ~ ., 
           data = GermanCreditTrain,
           method = "svmRadial")
```

Question: if this code is correct, how can it be run in a reasonable amount of time?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Question edited to make it more explicit that hours of runtime for a small dataset is problematic.

Comment: I don't have that issue. When I run it I get `svmFit$times$everything[3]` to be 5.36s and 8.602s sequentially. Can you look at `top` and see what VSIZE is for each worker while it is running? Without using multicore, I have VSIZE=2547M (caret version 6.0-24).

Comment: @topepo - thanks and sorry for the late reaction. Without multicore the whole thing runs in 10 seconds. With multicore nothing seems to happen, vsize = 693m.

Comment: I'm running into this issue as well. It seems to freeze with multi-core.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into incredibly poor performance of `svmRadial` on Linux. It turns out that the issue for me too was with using multicore `DoMC`. `svmRadial` runs fine on a single core. The `kernlab` functions are the only ones in `caret` that exhibit this behaviour that I've seen. This is very frustrating, as I had to drop multicore for my entire script just to get the SVM functions working.